# how to force xcode to use the correct iostream header c++

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, iostream

```
xcode 4.2
os x 10.7
```

when i set my includes to look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

I get the following error from a file located at `/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tr1`

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'boost/tr1/detail/config_all.hpp' file not found
```

Contents of the `/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tr1/iostream` file:

```
//  (C) Copyright John Maddock 2005.
//  Use, modification and distribution are subject to the
//  Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file
//  LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
//  This file exists to prevent std lib headers from accidentally
//  including a TR1 extention header; we must suppress this otherwise
//  we can end up with cyclic dependencies with some std lib implementations.
//
#ifndef BOOST_TR1_iostream_INCLUDED
#  define BOOST_TR1_iostream_INCLUDED
#  ifndef BOOST_TR1_NO_RECURSION
#     define BOOST_TR1_NO_RECURSION
#     define BOOST_TR1_NO_iostream_RECURSION
#  endif
#  include <boost/tr1/detail/config_all.hpp>
#  if defined(BOOST_HAS_INCLUDE_NEXT) && !defined(BOOST_TR1_DISABLE_INCLUDE_NEXT)
#     include_next <iostream>
#  else
#     include BOOST_TR1_STD_HEADER(iostream)
#  endif
#  ifdef BOOST_TR1_NO_iostream_RECURSION
#     undef BOOST_TR1_NO_iostream_RECURSION
#     undef BOOST_TR1_NO_RECURSION
#  endif
#endif
```

I should be using the iostream header located at `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/`

You will have to forgive me as I am very new to c++ and even more new to xcode.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What exactly did you do to customize your include paths so that it looks in /opt in the first place?

Comment: If i started my include paths before boost it would throw all sorts of errors.  Perhaps i need to take off recursive searches....

Comment: or rather tell it to search specifically what parts of boost i need rather than all of boost.  I am just afraid that if I dont include all of boost that it will break things.  I am too new at this to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely turn off recursive searches. You should never be able to include a boost header without specifying the complete boost path. Much of Boost is sort of a training ground for features that will make their way into the standard eventually, and as such there are a great number of Boost headers that share the same name as standard headers. There are also a bunch of boost headers that share the same name as other boost headers. There is no end to the grief this will cause you.